# Tabla con DataTables y Editor no me funciona

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, datatables

Estoy realizando una aplicación de inventario de equipos informáticos en PHP con Laravel. En estos momentos quiero mostrar una tabla con todos los datos sobre los modelos, pero no encuentro la solución.

Mi index para esta vista es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Datatables</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Editor/css/dataTables.editor.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Editor/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            ajax: $.ajax( {
                url: "/modelo",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
            } ),
            columns: [
                {data:"marca"},
                {data:"modelo"},
                {data:"part_number"},
                {data:"coste"},
                {data:"caractetisticas"},
                {
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edit">Editar</a> / <a href="#" class="Eliminar">Delete</a>'
                }
            ],
        });
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "actions.php",
            table: "#mytable",
            idSrc: "id",
            fields: [
                {label:'Marca' , name:'marca'},
                {label:'Modelo' , name:'modelo'},
                {label:'Part Number' , name:'part_number'},
                {label:'Coste' , name:'coste'},
                {label:'Características' , name:'caractetisticas'}
               ]
        });
        $('#mytable').on('click', 'a.edit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            editor
                .title( 'Editar modelo' )
                .buttons( { "label": "Update", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } } )
                .edit( $(this).closest('tr') );
        } );
        $('#mytable').on('click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            editor
                .message( '¿Estás seguro de eliminar el modelo?' )
                .buttons( { "label": "Delete", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } } )
                .remove( $(this).closest('tr') );
        } );
        $('a.create').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            editor
                .title( 'Crear nuevo modelo' )
                .buttons( { "label": "Add", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } } )
                .create();
        } );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="{!!URL::to('/modelo/create')!!}" class="create">Nuevo</a>
<table id="mytable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Coste</th>
            <th>Características</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Coste</th>
            <th>Características</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Y este es mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace inventario\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use inventario\Modelos;
use inventario\Http\Requests\ModelosRequest;

class ModeloController extends Controller
{
public function __construct(){
    //Para que no se pueda acceder a /usuario sin entrar por el login
    $this->middleware('auth');
    //Para dar permisos solo al usuario admin de acceder
    $this->middleware('admin');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $modelos = Modelos::all();
        return response()->json($modelos);
    }
    return view('modelos.index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('modelos.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(ModelosRequest $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        Modelos::create($request->all());
        return response()->json([
                "mensaje" => "creado"
            ]); 
    }

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $mdoelos = Modelos::find($id);

    return response()->json(
            $modelos->toArray()
        );
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $modelos = Modelos::find($id);
    $modelos->fill($request->all());
    $modelos->save();

    return response()->json([
            "mensaje"=>"listo"
        ]);
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $modelos = Modelos::find($id);
    $modelos->delete();

    return response()->json([
            "mensaje"=>"eliminado"
        ]);
}
}
```

Creo que mi error está en el "ajax", pero cuando inspecciono la web, observo que los datos sí me los está cargando:

[image: Inspector - Network]

Mi página cargada se ve de la siguiente manera (desconozco el motivo, pero tampoco me aparecen los botones Editar y Eliminar):

[image: Vista - Modelos]

Comment: Te muestra algún error en la consola JS?

Comment: Releyendo to pregunta, tienes un error tipográfico en la propiedad `características` al definir los campos, tienes escrito "caractetisticas".

Comment: He modificado la propiedad caracteristicas pero sigue sin funcionar. El error que me aparece en la consola es: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined'

Comment: Podrías tener un problema en el parseo del json. Lo que estás recibiendo es un `Array`, no un `Objeto`.

Comment: Por otra parte, al establecer la propiedad `ajax` del objeto `DataTable` estableces el resultado de una petición, no una url como establece la [documentación](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

Comment: Sí, es cierto, pero ¿cómo podría pasar por URL los datos que extraigo de mi base de datos? No sé cómo hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: Simplemente, establece la ruta en la propiedad `ajax`, así: `ajax: "/modelo"`

Comment: De esa manera, deja de cargarme los datos. Sigue sin funcionar. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: ¿Qué llamada está realizando? ¿O no hace ninguna? [Aquí](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) tienes un ejemplo de la documentación.

Comment: Realizo la llamada `ajax` al modelo, donde obtengo los datos mediante `json`. He probado con lo siguiente: `ajax: {url: "/modelo",type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', success: funtion(){console.log("Correcto")}}` Y no me devuelve por consola el mensaje _Correcto_. Si a su vez, también añado el de error, tampoco me devuelve nada.

Comment: lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Al final deje de usar Editor porque se me agotó el tiempo de prueba

Answer (score 1):

La llamada AJAX debe realizarla DataTables a partir de la url especificada, no debes poner el resultado de la llamada como parámetro:

```
var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        ajax: "/modelo",
        columns: [
            {data:"marca"},
            {data:"modelo"},
            {data:"part_number"},
            {data:"coste"},
            {data:"caractetisticas"},
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edit">Editar</a> / <a href="#" class="Eliminar">Delete</a>'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: He realizado la prueba y sigue sin cargarme los datos. Al inspeccionar la web, en la _Consola_ no aparece nada, tampoco en _Network_ ni en _Source_. Tampoco hay ningún rastro de json. Después de esta variable, añado al final lo siguiente `console.log("Fin de datatable")` y tampoco me lo muestra en _Consola_. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Comprueba que el número de columnas en `column` se corresponda con el marcado. Si no coinciden falla la ejecución de DataTables

Comment: He detectado que si añado `{data: null, defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edit">Editar</a> / <a href="#" class="Eliminar">Delete</a>'}` no termina, si lo quito, sí lo carga en el _Network_ pero no lo muestra por pantalla. En el _Network_ aparece lo siguiente: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/modelo?_=1493242046059` y su _Preview_ [{id: 1, marca: "HP", modelo: "EliteBook 840", part_number: "44G57TH", coste: 1,…}]. Creo que me falta muy poco. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Aun pasando el `ajax` de la siguiente manera, tampoco lo muestra en mi vista.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var datatable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                data: [
                {
                    "marca":"Prueba",
                    "modelo": "modelo",
                    "part_number": "12354",
                    "coste": "100",
                    "caracteristicas": "No se que hacer"
                }]
            },
            columns: [
                {data:"marca"},
                {data:"modelo"},
                {data:"part_number"},
                {data:"coste"},
                {data:"caracteristicas"},
                {{--{
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edit">Editar</a> / <a href="#" class="remove">Eliminar</a>'
                }--}}

            ]
        });
```